# Include file without references (or reference prefix)

Tags: python-sphinx, versioning, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I have a package documented on ReadTheDocs. I want to include the release notes for the newest release of my software both on the landing page and the dedicated release notes page (with the older versions’ notes)

Therefore I have my `release-new.rst`:

```
Version 0.7.4
=============
…

Version 0.7.3
=============
…
```

and `.. include::` it both in `index.rst` and `release-notes.rst`.

The problem arises when I want to add reference targets:

```
.. _v0.7.4:

Version 0.7.4
=============
…
```

The code for this target obviously gets included in both files, which means that docutils correctly complains about a duplicate reference target.

How can I include the file twice, but only have the reference targets in one of the documents? Is there a custom `include` directive alternative or a different way to define my reference?

Comment: There is no such feature. IMO this is a misuse of the purpose of an index. Nonetheless, if you must misuse it, then you can break your release-new.rst into several includes (`v0.7.4.rst`) and maintain two sets of unique targets followed by the include call, e.g., ``.. _index-v0.7.4:\n\n.. include:: v0.7.4` and ``.. _release-notes-v0.7.4:\n\n.. include:: v0.7.4`.

Comment: How is this a misuse? The main page version would simply display the information without being in the index.

Comment: Look up the definition of "index".